# Which Posix socket errors may be recoverable?

Tags: sockets, posix

Suppose I have established a connection on a socket and got a Posix error code while sending or receiving a packet: one of those listed at the end of [this page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html). On which errors I should *not* close the socket because trying to send/receive on the same socket again may work?

Comment: Do you have a list of error codes specific to your implementation?  The page you reference shows a fairly comprehensive `errno.h` catalog, not all of which are plausible for (AF_INET, TCP) socket operations.  ECHILD, for instance, is an unlikely send/recv error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK are recoverable. 
EINVAL maybe.
ECONNRESET, ENOTCONN, ECONNABORTED, EPIPE, EADDRINUSE, are definitely not.

Comment: you might want to add EINTR as well, since you're typically supposed to just retry the system call again.